# MacOS Catalina: Extend APFS Volume

Tags: merge, disk-utility, macos-catalina, apfs

Following is the result of `diskutil list` command:

[image]

I want to extend `disk0s2` to take up available space (29GB) since I have 128GB SSD and I have deleted container disk of size 29GB. I tried with disk utility but there is no option to extend the partition. Also I tried with `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 113g` command but throws below error:

```
Aligning grow delta to 26,99,96,44,160 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 1,10,99,99,98,464 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 84,00,03,54,304 bytes
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

How can I perform this operation using disk utility or cmd line?